# Azure Fabric Service - How to add one more service in same physical folder

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I created Service fabric on sub foder from root Folder.It has no option to select the Location when add one more service on same

[image: Add new Service]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the default location of where the project is located through this dialog.  You'll need to modify the location after creating the project through this dialog by manually moving things on disk and updating project/solution references.

Comment: Is there any challenges i am going to face while changing the physical location of the Project. Since it is service fabric, is there any configuration need to be done manually while deploy the Project

Comment: There shouldn't be.  As long as the project references are valid things should be good.